# Operations on mock.sentinel objects

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I really like `mock`'s sentinel values. It is a good way not to use random meaningless numbers in cases where you just want to write a minimal unit tests that covers one line.

However, the following

```
from mock import sentinel, patch

def test_multiply_stuff():
    with patch('module.data_source1',return_value=sentinel.source1):
        with patch('module.data_source1',return_value=sentinel.source1):
            assert function(module.data_source1,
                            module_data2) == sentinel.source1 * sentinel.source2
```

does not work. You'll get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: '_SentinelObject' and '_SentinelObject'
```

I understand why: It makes sense that operations on sentinel objects can't evaluate to an expression.

Is there some technique that does it (preferably within `mock`) ?

Is there some hack I can use? Or is the best thing you can do just to use exemplary numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the simplest way to do it is use `id(sentinel_object)` instead the sentinel itself:

```
from mock import sentinel, patch

def test_multiply_stuff():
    with patch('module.data_source1',return_value=sentinel.source1):
        with patch('module.data_source2',return_value=sentinel.source2):
            assert function(id(module.data_source1), id(module.data_source2) == id(sentinel.source1) * id(sentinel.source2)
```